# Save File using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have some screen scraped tabular data that I want to export to a CSV file (currently I am just placing it in the clipboard), is there anyway to do this in Greasemonkey?   Any suggestions on where to look for a sample or some documentation on this kind of functionality?

Just to be clear, I don't want to write to the local file system (I know that is impossible in the sandbox), but present a downloadable file - which may also be impossible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can't write it to a local CSV, but you might be able to write it to say a [Google Spreadsheet](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingSpreadsheets)?

Comment: Interesting idea.  I will definitely look into this, but may require a lot more work than I am willing to do for this and maybe it would be faster to make an actual Firefox add-on to gain access to the filesystem.

Answer (score 14):

```
var data='col1,col2\nval1,val2';
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
//supported by chrome 14+ and firefox 20+
a.download = 'data.csv';
//needed for firefox
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a);
//supported by chrome 20+ and firefox 5+
a.click();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h4jxx939/)

Comment: Combining this with [@Rub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33985544/315024) (by doing `a.href = makeTextFile(data, 'text/csv');` instead) was perfect.

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can do it using BLOB.

The script will attach content to a link that when clicked will offer to download a file (a file that never existed).

More info on:

- http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/
- [How to create .txt file using JavaScript / HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048215/how-to-create-txt-file-using-javascript-html5)

---

This is how I did it (there are many other ways to do it):

1. GM (greasemonkey) script generates the content of the file
2. GM passes it to the web page using sessionStorage.variable="...content.."
3. script within page makes link visible and attach the content of the variable to the BLOB object.

You many need to stringify / parse the object.

- contacts=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.contacts)
- sessionStorage.contacts=JSON.stringify(contacts);

---

I modified slightly the original script to make it generic for multiple mime types.

Here is mine.

```
// Stuff to create the BLOB object   --- ANY TYPE ---
var textFile = null,
//-- Function
makeTextFile = function (text,textType) {
    // textType can be  'text/html'  'text/vcard' 'text/txt'  ...
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: textType });
    // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
    // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
    if (textFile !== null) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }
    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    return textFile;
  };
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

alternative approach could be if you fire a javascript controlled http request for each cvs line you have to a local http server applet that is capable of storing (simple cgi or apache/php could do it easy)

Comment: that's my solution, but i can't get over CORS, even though I'm using header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *") in my php endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. http://wiki.greasespot.net/FAQ#Can_Greasemonkey_be_used_to_open_local_files.3F

Comment: I wasn't wanting to write to a local file, more like create a new file to be downloaded.

Comment: Any of the blob approaches will give you the file to download under user control.

Answer (score 0):

The free Javascript utility [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) uses the blob approach to generate a Zip file that pops up for you to download. The user script Fitocracy Bulk CSV used JSZip to collect the 100 files of workout data it generated.