# Storing into file using JavaScript/GreaseMonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have captured list of data from the page using Greasemonkey.

GM Script

```
var hit = GM_getValue("hit") || 0;
var _url = "http://localhost:8080/test?p=$$pageNo$$";
_url = _url.replace("$$pageNo$$", hit);
GM_setValue("hit", ++hit); 
if(hit <= 100) {
window.location.href = _url;
}
```

This script will runs for nth time and capture <10K data, now i facing the issue in storing the captured data in some file. 
Anyone has any idea about how we can store the captured data into file/repo?

Thanks
- Viswanathan G

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save File using Greasemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951149/save-file-using-greasemonkey)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, can't write it to a file, but if you're really bored, you can post it to http://pastebin.com (or any other URL that accepts a POST request with a bunch of data).

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://pastebin.com/post.php",
  data: <your data here>,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  onload: function(response) {
    alert("posted");
  }
});
```

Note you need to have a pastebin account to use the API.

---

If you **really** need to write a file to your local filesystem, run a web server on your desktop, and then save the results of an http PUT request to disk.

Comment: Its pretty good idea.
But if i am using xyz.com, is possible to send xmlHttpRequest in cross domain?

Comment: @gviswanathan Notice the `GM_xmlhttpRequest` object I'm using?  That's the magic that lets me send data **anywhere**.

Comment: > run a web server on your desktop, and then save the results of an http PUT request to disk.
Can it be explained in more details on how to do this? How exactly I need to run a web server? And how the "upload" need to be done to that server?

Answer (score 21):

A very fast and easy solution is to use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) :

1) Add the following line into the ==UserScript== section of your Greasemonkey script

```
// @require     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/dist/FileSaver.min.js
```

2. Add the 2 following lines of code to the GM script

   var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});

   saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");

   This code example will display a dialog box to download a file named "hello world.txt" containing the text "Hello, world!". Just replace this by the file name and the text content of your choice !

Comment: Nice idea! The current `require`has to be set for the URL `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/src/FileSaver.js`.

Comment: Same result, but you'd better get `// @require  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/dist/FileSaver.js`

Answer (score 8):

I use this trick to download a file from a Tampermonkey script:

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"});
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
```

Then call it with:

```
saveData("this data will be written in the file", "file.txt");
```

It works by creating a hidden element and simulating that element being clicked. It will behave as if the user clicked a download link, so the file will be downloaded by the browser, and saved wherever the browser puts downloaded files.

Comment: This is the one you all are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Based off https://stackoverflow.com/a/64500313/239916

```
// @grant        GM_download

function saveData(data, filename) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/plain" });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    GM_download({
        url: url,
        name: filename,
        saveAs: false,
    });
}

saveData("hello world", "hello.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can write to a file.
But not everywhere in the system, for obvious security reasons,
you can just write **in cookies directory**

```
  var cookie_name="YourCookie";
  var cookie_value="What you want to save inside your cookie";
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (28*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cookie_name +"=" + cookie_value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
```

You can then

- script a filecopy from cookie directory to your desktop, depending on
  your OS
- or read value from Chrome Inspect -> Application -> Cookies
- or retrieving the Cookie and print it in console with

  decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);

Comment: This works but remember you can only store 4096 bytes in cookie.