# How to get a value from a form with Greasemonkey and write it into a local file?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to read data from an URL and write this values to a local file with javascript and Greasemonkey.

for example:
my page :

```
<script>

function opens()
{
var x=document.getElementById('sval').value;
var y=document.getElementById('eval').value;
for(i=x;i<y;i++)
{
    window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript');
}
}
</script>
Start<input type='text' id='sval' ></input>
<br>
End<input type='text' id='eval'></input>
<br>
<button onclick='opens()'>a</button>
```

so:
in Greasemonkey I want to get value of search and then write to `c:\file.txt`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing into file using JavaScript/GreaseMonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392103/storing-into-file-using-javascript-greasemonkey)

Comment: Greasemonkey does not allow this.  The best you can do is send the data to a server.  The server (which you can set up on your own machine, would write the `file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You cant write a file to disc, but you do have a few options:

1- store the value in a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie)
2- [GM_setValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue)
3- [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB)

Comment: ok... so, Mr. Downvoter, i presume my answer is incorrect and it IS possible to write a file to disc with javascript?

Comment: Downvote may have occurred because your [answer contains only links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259).