# How to create .txt file using JavaScript / HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript . all codes available on the internet related to create text file using javascript is not working in my laptop. can anybody give me idea or with possible code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript code to save a txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854296/javascript-code-to-save-a-txt-file)

Comment: You should define "is not working". Maybe your browser is too old? Some of the examples use fairly new techniques.

Answer (score 9):

This code should work, give this a try and if this doesn't work then it may be an issue with your browser:

```
(function () {
var textFile = null,
  makeTextFile = function (text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

    // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
    // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
    if (textFile !== null) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }

    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

    return textFile;
  };


  var create = document.getElementById('create'),
    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

  create.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
    link.style.display = 'block';
  }, false);
})();
```

And the HTML:

```
<textarea id="textbox">Type something here</textarea> <button id="create">Create file</button> 
<a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
```

Taken from this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uselesscode/qm5ag/

Comment: its not working in both IE as well as in Chrome..what should i do?

Comment: It works in Firefox 38 and Chrome 43, but not IE10/11. The text file is generated and can be saved by right click > save as, but the listener for the download link doesn't work. I can't find an example that works in IE.

Answer (score 3):

A very fast and easy solution is to use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js

Then it takes only 2 lines of code to download a txt file :

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});

saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

This code example will display a dialog box to download a file named "hello world.txt" containing the text "Hello, world!". Just replace this by the file name and the text content of your choice !