# Adding a string(content) as a file to a html form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, post, forms

I'm looking for a way to add a string as a file inside a html form using JavaScript.

Now I know about the security issues the browsers have when it comes to files, but I'm **not** looking for adding a file path (as happens when you click the browse of a file input)!!
I want to add a **string as a file** (The server I'm hitting expects the post to include a file and not a simple form entry).

I know how to perform the action using the FormData object, but I don't want to generate a xhr(ajax) post. I need the post to be a simple form post since the server responds with a redirection.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: PHP would be able to create a fake file for you and do the post call through CURL.

Comment: What file type does it expect?

Comment: I need to do this using html + javascript.
The file type is a simple text file. The content is a base64 string.

Comment: So did you search and file questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048215/how-to-create-txt-file-using-javascript-html5 Does it help?

Comment: I did search SO and didn't find a suitable result.

Comment: I don’t think this is possible. You won’t get a simple HTML form to send all the right headers and the data in the right format unless it contains an actual file input.

Comment: @CBroe - I also can't think of a way to do this.
I can post a file with a FormData object and an xhr request - that's what made me think that there may be a to create a non xhr post request.

Comment: No, not really. You can not “insert” FormData back into a normal form or anything like that. // I am not really sure what you need/want to implement here anyway. If the remote server requires a file uploaded by the client - then what sense does it make to go through the process without having the actual user select a file in their browser in the first place? What do you need this address the server redirects to for - if you don’t seem to be following the intended use here in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe - Its kinda of a application deeplink that wants to receive information as a file (very weird). My intention is to create a form with a post request and perform the deeplink dynamically with a single click (the server also plants custom cookies - That's why I need the browsers help).